# Are large polynomials secure for order preserving "hashing"? (newbie question)

Tags: order-preserving

I've been searching for some time now for an answer to this simple question: if I have a large polynomial that is secret, and I use it to transform a set of integers so as to obtain a new set that preserves the order for each transformation, can the polynomial be deduced by an attacker only from the output?

Notes to take into consideration:

- The polynomial is carefully chosen to assure the outputs maintain order
- I'm working only with positive integers
- An attacker would only be able to see the generated outputs, never the inputs nor the polynomial (of course)
- The attacker could have access to large sets of generated outputs

One example of a valid polynomial could be: $$f(x) = 31x^{15}-27x^{14}+13x^{12}-10x^{9}+5x^{7} $$

Can the attacker deduce the polynomial from the output only, even if I make the polynomial much harder? Are polynomials even a possible solution for order-preserving "hashing"?

I assumed an attacker would be able to find out the secret polynomial through some fancy math tricks and algorithms, so I added the following three difficulties:

- I'm "pre-transforming" the input before inserting it into the polynomial by adding a large integer $\beta$ to it, so as to skew the input away from small positive integers - this $\beta$ value is unique per polynomial
- I'm "post-transforming" the generated outputs by dividing them with a common divisor as large as possible but that still maintains order - I'm doing this to take some information out of the generated outputs (the remainder) of the divisions. The common divisor is calculated the following way: $$commonDivisor = 10^{numDigits(f(1)-f(0))-1}$$
  where $numDigits(x)$ outputs the number of digits in the provided number.
- I'm also adding a random deviation value $\alpha$ to every output, that is small enough to not make it larger than the next output: $$out_{n-1}+\alpha_{n-1} < out_{n} + \alpha_{n}$$

All these operations together would produce something like the following:

$$f(x+\beta) = \frac{pol(x)+\alpha_x}{10^{numDigits(f(1)-f(0))-1}}$$

Continuing the previous question, would these changes make any real difference to the challenge of finding the polynomial, or are there ways to crack this?

A  not too technical answer would be very much appreciated due to my lack of experience in this field.

Comment: I would suggest to add some formal definitions in this question and structure the layout of the question, right now it is unnecessarily difficult to imagine what you actually mean. For formulas, please use MathJax (see the help options, basically latex code in between dollar signs)

Comment: In general, polynomial functions are not order-preserving. e.g; $f(x)=x^2-6x+9$ does not preserve the order of the triple $(1,2,6)$ which becomes $(4,1,9)$; are you restricting to non-negative coefficients for non-constant terms, and (odd powers or restriction to the domain of non-negative integers)? Assuming that, hint: how many examples does it take to find a polynomial from sample input/output pairs?

Comment: Are you doing your polynomial over the integers (or the reals), making sure that the polynomial is monotonic (at least, over the range of inputs you expect)?  I ask because, in the crypto world, if someone talks about polynomials, they're almost always talking about evaluating it over some finite ring or field...

Comment: @fgrieu - your right, I construct a polynomial that always assures order. The attacker doesn't have access to the input, only output. But lets assume I have transformed all integers from 0 to 1000. So the attacker would see 1000 ordered outputs.

Comment: @poncho - I'm working only with integers. Sorry for my lack of structure on my question.

Comment: I can't see how a polynomial of degree 15 can have 30 terms; nor how it could remain secret if 1001 input/output pairs are known (you state that the adversary knows the outputs, and the inputs are guessable, thus must be assumed known).

Comment: Seeing answers here in the comments, I still suggest adding some more information to the question, preferably in definitions and formulas. Reals vs Integers, modulos, number of variables, etc. Also if you consider your function/polynomial component wise (like in fgrieu's example) or actually as three variables.

Comment: @tylo - I will go edit my question. Thank you for your help. I don't know if I'll be able to make it as technically accurate as desired, though.

Comment: I edited my question  in order to try to clarify it better. Thank you for your help and patience.

Answer (score 4):

The basic method is easily cracked: it is well known how to find a polynomial of degree at most $k$ from $k+1$ (input, output) pairs; that's the [polynomial interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) problem. There are numerous ways to efficiently carry it for high degree and large integers (one such method is to carry it modulo some medium primes, and use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) in the end).

"pre-transforming" alone does not help at all against the above.

"post-transforming" and "adding a random deviation" makes recovering the polynomial more difficult. However, some simple attacks remain feasible, depending on adversarial model. In particular, if the adversary can query the function for arbitrarily large input: the degree of the polynomial and the highest degree coefficient of the polynomial divided by commonDivisor are easily found; then the attack can be repeated by subtracting known high coefficients, until finding all coefficients; in this setup, commonDivisor does not help much.

I do not see how to make the idea secure in a cryptographic sense.

Also: It does not seem that the "post-transforming" method proposed is guaranteed to maintain the property that distinct input leads to distinct output.

Addition following [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/39514/555#comment90099_39521): if input is not known, that makes attack harder; however

- you [proposed](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/39514/555#comment90077_39514): *lets assume I have transformed all integers from 0 to 1000*, and in cryptographic terms that's to be assimilated to a lot of known plaintext;
- known plaintext has been a standard assumption for about as long as cryptography matured to a science, for reasons similar to the above;
- as the saying goes: attacks only get better; they never get worse.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. May I argue that polynomial interpolation couldn't be used because it requires the attacker to know the  (input, output) pairs, as you mentioned. He only knows the outputs. Another thing you mentioned is the idea of querying the function for arbitrarily large input in order to make the term with the largest degree show itself. That is a great idea. One thing though, the attacker also doesn't have access to the function. So, I'm thinking that if I bound my inputs below a specific threshold, the largest degree doesn't show.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Now I understand why you were focused on the input-output idea. I didn't explain myself right, I'm sorry. I just wanted to state that only the output was visible to the attacker.

Comment: Only knowing the outputs is not a reasonable assumption. From today's point of view, known plaintext attacks (known pairs) are basically the lowest level of attacks a secure encryption scheme needs to withstand.

Comment: @tylo - I didn't know that. Thank you. Could you please point me where I can read about the different levels of attack an encryption scheme needs to withstand?

Comment: [Attack model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_model), and while we're at it: [Kerckhoffs' principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle). But I would suggest reading the entire context: [Cryptanalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptanalysis). I hope that's giving a good overview.